# spark example wont compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Trying to run one of apache sparks example codes (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/graphx/AggregateMessagesExample.scala) I get the following compile error

```
too many arguments for method sendToDst: (msg: (Int, Double))Unit
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]         triplet.sendToDst(1, triplet.srcAttr)
[error]                          ^
[error] one error found
```

But looking at the mehtods it seems to be correct. Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: send to dist expects a single tuple2[Int,Double] but you are passing in an Int and Double as two individual arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the method you are calling expects a single argument (a `Tuple2`) and you are passing in 2 arguments.

Try

```
triplet.sendToDst((1, triplet.srcAttr))
```

Comment: Thanks. Tuple works fine. Are case classes supported as well? Or would you rather suggest to stay with primitives here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: For passing messages using this aggregate messages function would you suggest to use type safe case classes instead of a tuple of primitives? Or would you rather suggest to stay with primitives for performance reasons ( less object creation in JVM)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with graphx to really comment, my answer was based entirely on the error message in your original question.

Comment: Tuples are also typed. In a REPL you can verify that val a = (1, "Word") produces a tuple a with type a: (Int, String)

Comment: I wanted to do that already, but SF told me to wait at least 10 minutes :) will do it now.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can look at the type signature of the method to see what types are allowed. Tuples are objects too so you don't save on object creation over a case class.  I would not expect a large difference in performance if any.